# How would you plot a regression in 3D that has an interaction and its CIs?

Tags: r, 3d, glm, confidence-interval

First of all this is my data:

```
df<-data.frame(fpergandei=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
mintemp2=c(1.29569224,1.40509105,0.74869815,1.51448987,2.49907923,-1.00168292,
-0.01709357,-0.34529002,-0.56408765,-0.01709357,0.20170407,0.42050170,-1.00168292,
-1.98627227,0.09230525,-0.23589120,-0.78288528,-0.89228410,-0.01709357,1.95208514,
0.31110289,0.31110289,0.09230525,0.96749579,-0.23589120,-0.01709357,-1.22048055,
-0.23589120,-0.45468883,-0.67348647,-1.65807582,-0.45468883),
moist2=c(0.24947803,-1.17491998,0.05498936,-1.58242006,-1.46943140,2.16472842,1.64979649,
1.65535331,-1.00821540,0.40506897,-0.22840843,-0.28027207,0.92370544,1.04039865,
1.36639871,1.32564870,-0.18210160,-0.25248798,-0.81557900,-0.72481762,-1.75282919,
-0.58219259,-0.27286298,-0.07281749,0.07536436,-0.04688566,-0.41363574,-0.54699940,
-0.19691978,0.89036452,0.84035315,-1.03785177))

df
   fpergandei    mintemp2      moist2
1           0  1.29569224  0.24947803
2           0  1.40509105 -1.17491998
3           0  0.74869815  0.05498936
4           0  1.51448987 -1.58242006
5           0  2.49907923 -1.46943140
6           0 -1.00168292  2.16472842
7           0 -0.01709357  1.64979649
8           0 -0.34529002  1.65535331
9           1 -0.56408765 -1.00821540
10          1 -0.01709357  0.40506897
11          1  0.20170407 -0.22840843
12          1  0.42050170 -0.28027207
13          0 -1.00168292  0.92370544
14          0 -1.98627227  1.04039865
15          0  0.09230525  1.36639871
16          0 -0.23589120  1.32564870
17          1 -0.78288528 -0.18210160
18          1 -0.89228410 -0.25248798
19          1 -0.01709357 -0.81557900
20          1  1.95208514 -0.72481762
21          1  0.31110289 -1.75282919
22          1  0.31110289 -0.58219259
23          1  0.09230525 -0.27286298
24          1  0.96749579 -0.07281749
25          1 -0.23589120  0.07536436
26          1 -0.01709357 -0.04688566
27          1 -1.22048055 -0.41363574
28          1 -0.23589120 -0.54699940
29          1 -0.45468883 -0.19691978
30          1 -0.67348647  0.89036452
31          1 -1.65807582  0.84035315
32          1 -0.45468883 -1.03785177
```

note i factorized "fpergandei" to make it two levels of 1 and 0

So I recently ran a GLM binomial with two continuous explanatory variables. The results yielded in a significant interaction between the two explanatory variables. I ended up plotting the model using the persp() function

```
mylogit<- glm(fpergandei~mintemp2*moist2,data=fedelog,family="binomial")
press_grid <- seq(-2.2, 2.2, by = 0.1)
v_grid <- seq(-2.2, 2.2, by = 0.1)
newdat <- data.frame(mintemp2 = rep(press_grid, times = length(v_grid)), 
moist2 = rep(v_grid, each = length(press_grid)))
pred <- predict.glm(mylogit, newdata = newdat, type="response")
z <- matrix(pred, length(press_grid))
res<-persp(press_grid, v_grid, z, xlab = "Min. Temperature", ylab = 
"Moisture", zlab = "Predicted Probability", main = "Plot Name", theta = 60, 
phi = 27, col = mycol)
```

I've also figured out how to use the persp function to plot confidence intervals.

```
pred2 <- predict.glm(mylogit, newdata = newdat, type="response", se.fit = 
TRUE)#with confinterval
pred$se.fit #standard errors for all predicted values
CIlow <- exp(pred-1.96*pred2$se.fit)/(1+exp(pred-1.96*pred2$se.fit)) 
#calculating lower confidence interval 
CIup <- exp(pred+1.96*pred2$se.fit)/(1+exp(pred+1.96*pred2$se.fit))  
#calculating upper confidence intervals
```

My issue is that when I plot surfaces of the upper and lower confidence intervals they overlap over and under each other:

```
res<-persp(press_grid, v_grid, ci.low, xlab = "Min. Temperature", ylab = 
"Moisture", zlab = "Predicted Probability", main = "Lower Confidence 
Interval", theta = 60, phi = 27, col = "grey") #surface w/ CI low
par(new=TRUE)
res<-persp(press_grid, v_grid, z, xlab = "Min. Temperature", ylab = 
"Moisture", zlab = "Predicted Probability", main = "Logistic Curve)", theta 
= 60, phi = 27, col = mycol) #surface with pred
par(new=TRUE)
res<-persp(press_grid, v_grid, ci.up, xlab = "Min. Temperature", ylab = 
"Moisture", zlab = "Predicted Probability", main = "Upper Confidence 
Interval", theta = 60, phi = 27, col = "grey") #surface w/ CI low
```

Is there any way I can make it so that the surface plots end up not overlapping each other and just creating a mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt with plotly. Good thing about this approach is that you can rotate the view till you are satisfied with the perspective

```
library(plotly)

mylogit <- glm(fpergandei ~ mintemp2 * moist2, 
               data = df,
               family = "binomial")
```

the following two vectors can be called "mintemp2" and "moist2" I kept the following names because of the OP

```
press_grid <- seq(-2.2, 2.2, by = 0.1)
v_grid <- seq(-2.2, 2.2, by = 0.1)
newdat <- expand.grid(press_grid, v_grid)  #the grid results in the same values as the newdat in the OP
colnames(newdat) <- c("mintemp2", "moist2")

pred <- predict.glm(mylogit, newdata = newdat, type="link", se=TRUE)

ymin <- mylogit$family$linkinv(pred$fit - 1.96 * pred$se.fit)
ymax <- mylogit$family$linkinv(pred$fit + 1.96 * pred$se.fit)
fit <- mylogit$family$linkinv(pred$fit) 
z <- matrix(fit, length(press_grid))
ci.low <- matrix(ymin, length(press_grid))
ci.up <- matrix(ymax, length(press_grid))


plot_ly(x = press_grid, y = v_grid) %>% 
  add_surface(z = z,
              colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("red","blue"))) %>% 
  add_surface(z = ci.low, opacity = 0.5, showscale = FALSE, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("grey","grey"))) %>% 
  add_surface(z = ci.up, opacity = 0.5, showscale = FALSE, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("grey","grey")))
```

[image]

Here is an idea how to plot this in 2 dimensions which I think is more effective

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(pred = fit,
           low = ymin,
           high = ymax,
           newdat) %>%
  filter(moist2 %in%  unique(.$moist2)[c(T, rep(F, 3))]) %>%
  mutate(facet = factor(rep(c("-2.2 - -1.4", "-1 - -0.2", "0.2 - 1", "1.4 - 2.2"), each = length(.$moist2)/4),
                        levels = c("-2.2 - -1.4", "-1 - -0.2", "0.2 - 1", "1.4 - 2.2")),
         moist2 = as.factor(moist2)) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = mintemp2, y = pred, color = moist2))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = mintemp2, ymin = low, ymax = high, fill = moist2), alpha = 0.1)+
  facet_wrap(~facet, ncol = 2)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

In general using fewer values of one variable, and spiting the range into facets. At first look one can see the 0.2 - 1 moist2 range changes the direction of the probability function which I think is quite interesting and emphasizes the interaction of these two variables. Something I failed to see with the 3D plot.

Comment: Thanks! I had a question about the new confidence intervals in plot though. Those CI bands are going above 1 and below zero in your last plot. Is that accurate or just a graphical problem?

Comment: Sweet. I wish there was a better way to do this. You can see that half of one CI surface does the lower confidence interval and the other half does the upper resulting in poor graphics..sigh

Comment: yes exactly! transparent volumes depicting CI intervals while the actual logistic model is a non-transparent surface? if that makes any sense?

Comment: @Leo Ohyama I found an error in the calculation of the CI. Check edit, The result is a much narrower CI region as one would expect. I will look in to the transparent volume and will post what I find.

Comment: thank you so much! Any update would be awesome. But yeah I had no clue you could go into the model and get the inverse of the link like that.

Comment: @Leo Ohyama I've added a 2D plotting approach which I trust conveys information about the model more directly than any 3d plot could, If you are interested in plotting the SE as a volume look into `mash3d` type of plot in `plotly`. I would post a solution with it, however I failed to make it work on my PC even with the simplest examples on plotly site. I trust it has to do with the GFX driver.

Comment: thanks for the other approach, my colleague agreed that using a 2d perspective would be better in terms of presenting the model. Could u still post the mash3d() code, perhaps y setup could run it?

Comment: @Leo Ohyama my mash3d code is not functional since I am unable to error test it due to hard/soft problems and I am quite sure it will not work as is. My problem with the mash is to translate the two surface coordinates of the upper and lower CIs to one closed 3D mash. Hard to accomplish if the mash is not visible.

Comment: got it. Well thank you for the help. I appreciate it